# Determining Effects of Natural Selection on Mermaids

Tags: natural-growth, mermaid

Okay, after a lot of thought, I decided that mermen wouldn't exist in my setting. Why? Because in various IRL situations, balance is necessary for proper function. If men represent land and mermaids represent the sea, the two together represent a perfect balance. (There is still human women, I didn't see any reason to remove them from the setting.) However, this comes with a price.

Due to the constraints of their environment, mermaids will be stuck at pre-medieval levels of technology, as they can't work metal, create fire...in essence, they lack the resources and quite possibly the motivation to develop anything truly advanced. ("We've been doing this for years, why would we change it?" AKA "don't mess with success.")

In other words, **part of my premise** is the idea that mermaids will survive with primitive technology (coral branches as improvised spears, for instance), focusing instead on the social aspects of life (relationships, altruism, cooperation). **This means** they'll have an intricate culture, lots of social rituals, and an emphasis on teamwork and relationships but lousy tech.

**This also means** that mermaids will likely put even more emphasis on increasing desirability than regular people do-firstly, they are only part human, which could very well hurt their chances with potential mates, and secondly, with their society's focus on relationships, plus the fact that *their survival literally depends on this and failure threatens the whole species*, **it seems obvious** mermaids will undergo intense sexual selection.

My question is, **How Will Mermaids Be Influenced by Sexual Selection?**

**Specifications:**

1. I really don't want or need a ton of detail, just generalities are fine. You can even sum up by saying "this will inevitably lead to a Hollywood phenotype among mermaids," if that's accurate.

**If you don't feel such a sum-up is possible, feel free to use the following list of traits and explain how natural selection will influence them:**

a. Hair length/color
b. Scale color/appearance
c. Skin color (maybe texture?)
d. Fin appearance
e. Fishtail form (appearance, not function)
f. General appearance

2. **The best answer** will be realistic; I am a fictional realist, I put realism into my fiction, so input on realistic mermaid traits will be appreciated. Just know that mermaids are basically magic-born chimeras, female humans altered by an ancient cataclysmic event into the half-fish creatures they are now, so they will have both skin and scales *at first, barring natural selection.*

I say 'barring natural selection' because such a topic as mermaids having scales *and* skin or just scales is *exactly* what Spec #2 concerns, namely, realism. I'm all for traditional mermaid depictions, but I understand that may not be possible when natural selection is applied. Anyway, thank you and good luck!

Comment: Are you saying that there are only human males and female mermaids in your story? Like an extreme case of sexual dimorphism? Or are there still human women?

Comment: @LiveInAmbeR: There are still human women, which I added to the OP. Thanks for asking, I didn't realize that there was cause for confusion there!

Comment: Are you saying that in your world "_women have the tendency to act catty and judge based on appearances_" or are you suggesting this is a real world truism that you wish to motivate how your fictional world will function?

Comment: @JonSG: I am a writer who prefers realism in fantasy, and I believe this is a real-world problem that will affect the function of my fictional world. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I hope I cleared things up for you.

Comment: If you are a realist, then I recommend you abandon the notion that females are somehow predisposed to be catty or superficial and look to the overwhelming body of evidence that suggests it is the female who is selective when mating and the male who beatifies and performs for her attention not the other way around.

Comment: @Alendyias The issue is that you're projecting today's vision (or some say stereotypes) of gender in modern, occidental worlds towards a pre-medieval one, which on top isn't in the same environment and with a totally different, "mono-gender" species, a situation where things could evolve differently. Anyhow, that's some words that will grow the eyebrows of some people, so expect things to run wild :p.

Comment: @JonSG: noted and appreciated, though I have observed that while this notion is by no means super-prevalent, it can be a problem. As for the overwhelming evidence you mention, I can't help but think that it'd be different in this case, despite knowing full well I could be wrong.

Comment: @JonSG: I have made an edit with your point and Tortliena's in mind, please let me know if it's an improvement.

Comment: Also slightly more outside the question, a balance is made when there is an equilibrium between forces or entities. If human women are part of the sexual interests, you risk facing a 1-to-2 male-to-female relationships. Unless you balance population values, expect a lot of funny love triangles :p (but why not?).

Comment: @Alendyias Legends of mermaids and their captivating beauty are sometimes attributed to Manatesss. I think that tells us everything we need to know : https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/article/141124-manatee-awareness-month-dugongs-animals-science

Comment: @Tortliena: ah, I will _definitely_ want to avoid that, thanks for the tip! I think the idea of female-only species is interesting and want to include them in my setting, but I really don't like love triangles.

Comment: @Alendyias The point I rose is related to this [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/210939/80336), you might want to check how that went there. Note it's for supposedly land walking males however ^^.

Comment: @Tortliena: I checked the link, I can see what you mean. However, I'm not sure how well it applies since A) mermaids can't kidnap air-breathers, B) they can't effectively come on land to get them, and C) I believe there is a reason women are called the gentler sex, and that this makes kidnapping unlikely for an all-female species?

Comment: @Alendyias Hence the warning, you'll have to adapt. Though, here are some help : For B, catch fishermen. For C : They're mermaids, so they can be harsh-willed for their survival or anywhere towards kind. Because the premises are different, you have more freedom of choice ;).

Comment: @Alendyias You're missing the low hanging fruit. Rape is a thing. Believe it or not, women can rape men, and can be just as sexually aggressive (especially if mating opportunities are not readily available due to the "choosy female" paradigm). A much smaller fish can drag a large man into the water because of physics and their tails being *much* more powerful (see: *River Monsters*). It would be trivial for your mermaids to drag unsuspecting men into the water and have their way with them to perpetuate their species. Indeed a lot of folklore and classic literature has merfolk doing just this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems impossible to answer since any evolutionary process that results in "all-female species that can inter-breed with humans" is not a process as happens in the real world. Such a process is usually referred to as 'Fictional And Narrative SElective Reverse VanIty Contrived Evolution'

Assuming this is already covered somehow (i.e. by the species being able to reproduce asexually but gaining some benefit from incorporating human DNA, like more variation/healthier offspring), I'd argue that there isn't a tremendous amount of pressure on the mermaids to evolve towards being 'more attractive' than human females. **The reason being that they don't really compete with human females in the first place.**

Assuming 'standard' mermaids that live in the water most of the time and can breathe both air and water (or hold their breath for prolonged periods), most of their encounters will be with ships full of sailors* which are overwhelmingly male for all of human history. Females onboard exist as passengers and in more modern times as crew, but for most of human history, most seafaring was done by adolescent young males who were at sea for months at a time. If they encounter a group of actual mermaids, not the manatees mentioned in a comment, it does not take a lot for mating to happen. Especially since the men would not need to, or be able to, stay around to raise the offspring. Cultural and moral barriers wouldn't really be able to hold the hormones at bay.

The question is whether the humans would trust the mermaids enough to get close enough for this to happen, since traditionally mermaids are considered a danger to seafolk for various reasons. So the mermaids primary objective would be to 'be helpful' to sailors, and there's a lot that intelligent, aquatic mammals can do in order to be helpful to ships in the age of sail at least. Provide navigational aid, supply fresh fish, perhaps give information on other ships in the area or warn them of shoals and other dangers to ships in the area. To that end they might develop organs that help them navigate (perhaps some kind of internal compass so they always know North?) or otherwise. Presumably, they'd usually flock around areas dangerous for ships to warn them of the danger - or perhaps wait until a ship has run aground so they can take their pickings then.

*Given the nature of the question, I request extra points for not putting the other word there.

Comment: Great point on trust, I didn't think of that! As for the feasibility of my premise, yes I know it's a bit much, but that's kind of the fun for me: explaining the supposedly unexplainable.

Comment: You're wrong there is an example of this happening in our world. There are serval kinds of animals  That after the loss of the entire male population the female population mates with the closest similar species  To trigger her body to fertilize its own eggs making a genetic clone of the female.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenogenesis

Comment: I also disagree that  Natural selection wouldn't have a place here. Is true they aren't competing against. Human females but they are competing against each other. It would be natural for those that human  males  Found more attractive to get more mates and therefore more offspring

Comment: Good point on the Parthenogenesis. 
The 4th paragraph of the question referred to their desirability vs. humans (or at least implied it) and I focused my answer on that mostly. The goal was to provide a different perspective than the previously given (and imo correct) answer that they would evolve much the same way to be attractive as human females did.

Comment: This was and is a great answer, but upon further consideration some questions have arose in my mind, and I'd greatly appreciate if you could address them. Even accounting for how sailors won't be picky, won't they overwhelmingly prefer the prettiest mermaids and ignore the others? If so, how would that influence mermaid development?

Comment: How big is your mermaid population? How large groups do they travel or live in? A first rate ship of the line during the age of sail had a crew of 500-600 men. Other sailing vessels would have less crew but still significant amounts. Do your mermaids live in cities or pods?

Answer (score 2):

You wrong about technology. Mermaids can use radioactive materials in the place of fire.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=nvYCUSvW7LA&t=548s

As for traits sexual attraction tends to evolve towards health, fertility and survival.

So for the human half probably be what most humans find attractive. Large breast,(fertility) larger ass (survival), birthing hips (fertility), long hair (health)and so on.

For the fish we would see large muscular tails that can give the mermaids more power when moving through the water.  Perhaps brighter colors that can be more easily camouflaged in coral.

Since there competing with human woman there would probably evolve to be much more fertile and more likely to  have twins or triplets.

Comment: Interesting perspective, thank you!